# VueJs 3 - Use bundled sfc combined with Client Side Rendering

Tags: javascript, c#, vue.js, asp.net-core, vuejs3

### Greetings

Hello fellow Vuers!

So I've got the following situation:

I use **ASP.Net Core 3.1** as my server and I would like to use the **Vue SFC setup** including Typescript support and bind the resulting components into my **.cshtml**.

### Example Usage

#### Example.vue

```
<template>
    <label :for="name">{{ content }}</label>
    <input :id="name" :placeholder="content"/>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
     someCode
}),
</script>

<style scoped>
    /*some styling*/
</style>
```

#### Index.cshtml.cs

```
public class IndexModel: PageModel{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

#### Index.cshtml

```
@page
@model Namespace.To.IndexModel
<example :name="@Model.Name" :content="@Model.Content" />
```

### The Question

Is there a way to **bundle** the **Single File Components** and then use the Components *as needed* inside of a **.(cs)html**?

Preferably I'd like to have each component inside of it's own .js file to load them on demand, but it's not a must have.

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. But to clarify, it seems like you want to use the components individually. That means that what you're calling a SFC/component, will need to be treated as its own Vue app.

Assuming that's the case, instead of making the components bundled separately you'll need to create a vue app for each one, and individually export them.

You will need to decide how/when to mount them. I've relied on a more manual way of mounting, which requires a line of js to link the DOM element with the *widget* and pass the attributes. Alternatively you can rely on the DOM tag only. Admittedly, the js way is a bit more verbose, but less prone to edge cases.

Here is the example for the js way

`components/example/index.js`:

```js
import Example from './Example.vue';

export const mountExample = (el, props) =>
  Vue.createApp(el, props);
```

Then will wrap the component in a function that allows you to pass the DOM element to use and the props.

You would need

```html
<script src="vue.js"/><!-- if it's not bundled in there -->
<script src="example.js"/>
<div id="example" />
<script>
  mountExample('#example', {name:"@Model.Name", content="@Model.Content});
</script>
```

The other way (without the js instantiation) would be to wrap it in a function (IIFE) that looks for `<example>` tags, parses the content and then mounts the app with the provided parameters. It's quite a bit more work than the other example, but shouldn't be terribly complex.

So for the Example example, I'd organize it something like this: `example`

```
/components/example/
|-- Example.vue
|-- index.js
```

and then use webpack chaining via `vue.config.js` to do multiple of these

```js
module.exports = {
  // tweak internal webpack configuration.
  // see https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/webpack.md
  chainWebpack: config => {
    // remove the standard entry point
    config.entryPoints.delete('app')

    // then add your own
    config.entry('example')
      .add('./src/components/example/index.js')
      .end()
    .entry('menu')
      .add('./src/components/menu/index.js')
      .end()
  }
}
```

A caveat; I've used rollup to generate these and I haven't tested this, but webpack should work too

resources for the webpack config:

- https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration
- https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain